# Node.js installation using nvm

Tags: node.js, development-environment, nvm

I am trying to install *node.js* on mac running macOS Sierra using **nvm** but after installing nvm when I try to run
 `nvm install node` it says `Version 'node' not found - try nvm ls-remote to browse available versions.`

when I run `nvm ls-remote` I only get list of *io.js* and not node.

**does nvm now support the node installation or just only io.js?**
Please help me figure it out or should I just go with the standard package installer.

Comment: Might be worth adding which OS/Distro you are running.

Comment: use nvm install <NODE_VERSION >

Comment: tried with version number no use.

Comment: What version of nvm are you using? (Run `nvm --version`)

Comment: Which version of NVM do you use? Maybe you try http://boekhoff.net/how-to-install-nodejs-and-npm-using-nvm-and-zsh-nvm/

Answer (score 1):

I am suspecting you don't have the nvm script in your startup files. Hope this helps.
First make sure you have a base Node.js version installed.

```
brew install node
```

This will get you the latest stable Node.js version. You can now proceed to installing `NVM` using either `curl or wget`. Also remember to add the scripts to your `~/.zshrc` file assuming you're using zsh

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

To install Node.js version after successfully setting up `NVM`

```
nvm install v6.9.1
```

If all fails you can also use [N: Node Version Manager](https://github.com/tj/n)

Comment: actually I had the nvm script in my startup file particularly in bash_profile. But anyways i shifted to use N. anyways thanks.